# IntrinsicHeight makes size animation broken

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a layout where I have a row and inside this row, I have a custom expansion tiles list and a custom widget, which is a rectangle with a fixed width of 5 pixels, the height of the rectangle must be the same, as the expansion tile's height.
To make the rectangle the same height as the expansion panel, I used intrinsic height.
So, the structure is this IntrinsicHeight: Row: [ExpansionPanel, Container]
The problem is that when I use IntrinsicHeight all animations are broken.
Animation in the expansion tile list is working, but the container which contains the row does not resize following the animation, but does it without any intermediate steps.

I have tried to use different types of animation.

```
Implicit tween animation builder
     return TweenAnimationBuilder(
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: opened ? 1 : 0),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      builder: (_,double value, __){
        return ClipRect(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            heightFactor: value,
            child: value != 0 ? body : null,
            ),);
        }
    );
Cross fade animation
return AnimatedCrossFade(
    firstChild: body,
    secondChild: Container(height: 0,),
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
    crossFadeState: opened ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
    sizeCurve: Curves.ease,
);
```

Changing animation type didn't fix my problem.

My questions are following:

1. Is there an option to make an animation of size simultaneously using IntrinsicHeightWidget
2. If there is not such an option, Is there an option to make a Rectangle widget with the same height as an expansion tile list, but without the IntrinsicHeight widget.

I have captured a video to show how the problem looks like.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpQ8QHwHUWQ

I have seen similar problems, but I didn't get success implementing them in my case.

- [Flutter - Animate change on height when child of container renders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53768384/flutter-animate-change-on-height-when-child-of-container-renders)
- [Stretch children of a Flutter Row to the maximum *natural* height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58508379/stretch-children-of-a-flutter-row-to-the-maximum-natural-height)
- [How to stretch Containers inside Row to maximum available height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63520019/how-to-stretch-containers-inside-row-to-maximum-available-height)